# Dependency graph. Parallel processing

Tags: c#, graph, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library

I need to realize dependecies from the dependency graph using TPL (all processes must start parallel). Here is my code:

```
TaskFactory factory = Task.Factory;

// 1 and 6
Task task_1 = factory.StartNew(() => A());
Task task_6 = factory.StartNew(() => F());

// 4 and 6
Task task_2 = task_1.ContinueWith((t) => B());
Task task_4 = task_6.ContinueWith((t) => D());

// 5 and 7
Task task_5 = task_2.ContinueWith((t) => E());
Task task_7 = task_4.ContinueWith((t) => G());

// 3
Task task_3 = factory.ContinueWhenAll(new[] { task_1, task_2, task_4, task_5, task_6, task_7 }, (tasks) => C());
Task.WaitAll(task_3);
```

All my methods look like:

```
private static void A()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1");
}
```

Is there more elegant solution?

Comment: In what way do you think the current solution is inelegant?

Comment: svick, I only try to study parallel programming and want to know if there is better way to implement this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since most of your graph consists of simple paths, you could simplify your code to something like (assuming the dependency graph is fixed):

```
Task task125 = factory.StartNew(() => { A(); B(); E(); });
Task task647 = factory.StartNew(() => { F(); D(); G(); });

Task.WaitAll(task125, task647);

C();
```

Comment: svick, thank you very much! I have a question: are dependencies A->B->E saved in your solution? I mean is it guaranteed that method B() wouldn't be implemented before method A()?

Comment: @user3649515 Yes, that's how normal procedural programming works, it's guaranteed that `B()` will be called (not “implemented”, that doesn't make sense here) only after `A()` returns.